# Python regular expression not matching

Tags: python, regex

This is one of those things where I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but... In the sample program below, I'm trying to use Python's RE library to parse the string "line" to get the floating-point number just before the percent sign, i.e. "90.31".  But the code always prints "no match".

I've tried a couple other regular expressions as well, all with the same result.  What am I missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
line = '    0 repaired, 90.31% done'
pct_re = re.compile(' (\d+\.\d+)% done$')
#pct_re = re.compile(', (.+)% done$')
#pct_re = re.compile(' (\d+.*)% done$')
match = pct_re.match(line)
if match: print 'got match, pct=' + match.group(1)
else: print 'no match'
```

Comment: I knew it was something trivial!  Thanks everyone for your quick and helpful replies.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`match` only matches from the *beginning* of the string. Your code works fine if you do `pct_re.search(line)` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `re.findall` instead:

```
>>> line = '    0 repaired, 90.31% done'
>>> 
>>> pattern = re.compile("\d+[.]\d+(?=%)")
>>> re.findall(pattern, line)
['90.31']
```

`re.match` will match at the start of the string. So you would need to build the regex for complete string.

Answer (score 2):

try this if you really want to use match:

```
re.match(r'.*(\d+\.\d+)% done$', line)
```

r'...' is a "raw" string ignoring some escape sequences, which is a good practice to use with regexp in python. – kratenko (see comment below)

Comment: You might want to add, that the `r'...'` is a "raw" string ignoring some escape sequences, which is a good practice to use with regexp in python.